# Magnific-popup just links to youtube video, doesn't show in pop up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, youtube, magnific-popup

I have a video link that I want to open up in a pop up using Magnific, but when it clicks, it just links to the Youtube url. I suspect that some JS code isn't being read, but I'm returning 0 errors.

Currently my div looks like this:

```
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pzot1TWuutY" class="magnific-youtube">
<span class="fa fa-play-circle"></span>
</a>
```

My JS Function looks like this:

```
// Magnific JS
$( document ).ready(function(){
$('.magnific').magnificPopup({
  type:'image',
  removalDelay: 300,
  mainClass: 'mfp-fade'
});

$('.magnific-youtube, .magnific-vimeo').magnificPopup({
  disableOn: 700,
  type: 'iframe',
  mainClass: 'mfp-fade',
  removalDelay: 300,
  preloader: false,
  fixedContentPos: false
});
```

I've linked to all the required files, but can't seem to get the plug in to file.

**[Here is my demo of it](http://www.donorpro.com/home-clone)** Just scroll down to the part with 3 images + play buttons.

Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: Nothing is happening for me when I click on the 2nd and 3rd images. Is this on purpose or did you do something different here?

Comment: No, the code is only on the first one right now, my mistake, should have mentioned it!

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**

Try this for your HTML:

```
<div class="magnific-youtube">
<span class="fa fa-play-circle"></span>
  Open video
</div>
```

Try this for your javascript:

```
    $('.magnific-youtube').magnificPopup({
    items: {
      src: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pzot1TWuutY'
    },
    type: 'iframe' 
});
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to do anything, I pulled the `href` and kept the `<a>` tags and it just clicks but doesn't fire off anything

Comment: Oddly enough I had it running in my own codepen as well, but when I transfer it to my site it doesn't want to work lol. http://codepen.io/TyStelmach/pen/gapzxX

Comment: I see that you have two different jquery libraries in your code. Try it with just one and I'd use this CDN: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: I'd also try the unminified version of the magnific javascript and disable the carosel script just to see if there are any conflicts. Has to be one of these dependencies causing problem if it's working in codepen.

Answer (score 0):

try changing the link from

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pzot1TWuutY

to

> https://www.youtube.com/embed/pzot1TWuutY

change `/watch?v=` to `/embed/`